# Create a table/view with looks like the pages of a book

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was doing a test online and I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem.

There's a recipe table with page, title.
The content is:

```
1, omelette
2, hamburger
3, pizza
4, apple pie
6, cherry pie
```

0 and 5 are missing. 0 is considered the first page of the book (on the left).

The output should be like this:

```
NULL, omelette
hamburger, pizza
apple pie, NULL
cherry pie, NULL.
```

I create a query in postgresql:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN mod (page, 2) = 0 then title else 'NULL'
END AS even_title,
CASE WHEN mod (page, 2) <> 0 then title else 'NULL'
END AS odd_title
FROM recipes;
```

The issue is that my result is

```
NULL, omelette
hamburger, NULL
NULL, pizza
apple pie, NULL
cherry pie, NULL.
```

Comment: . . Are you using Postgres or MS Access?  Your last question turned out to be about MS Access.

Comment: I told you in my last question that I was using both. In this case, I am putting postgresql because I know that the CASE instruction doesn't exist in Access.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all even page numbers and join the appropriate pages to it:

```
SELECT left_page.title, right_page.title
FROM generate_series(0, (SELECT max(page) / 2 * 2 FROM recipes), 2) AS lp(lp)
   LEFT JOIN recipes AS left_page
      ON left_page.page = lp.lp
   LEFT JOIN recipes AS right_page
      ON right_page.page = lp.lp + 1
ORDER BY left_page.page;
```

This will return NULL for pages that don't exist. Use `coalesce` if you want the string `NULL` instead.

Comment: Alternative way is to generate consequtive numbers and group by trunc(page/2) with single join

Comment: This gives me an error: lp.page doesn't exist.
I don't know the generate_series instruction as I am new to postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select
max(case when id%2=0 then value end) as even_page,
max(case when id%2=1 then value end) as odd_page
from t1  
group by id/2
order by id/2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.
Can you explain why the group by and order by are by id/2?

Comment: @Stef, it just to create the row index, btw if it helped u please don't forget to mark it as accepted answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet:

```
SELECT
r1.title AS even_title,
r2.title AS odd_title
FROM recipes r1 full outer join recipes r2 on r1.page+1 = r2.page
where r1.page % 2 = 0 or r2.page % 2 = 1
order by r1.page;
```